# Programming for Windows Embedded 6.5/Mobile 6.5 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-embedded

I'm searching for a long time. There is something I need to hear from those who have experience with the application and the project.

In Visual Studio 2015:

- Windows Mobile 6.5
- Windows Embedded
  Handheld 6.5

Can I develop applications for SDKs?

The key here is that I can not delete 2015. But I can use plugins etc.

Thanks to for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to program for Windows Mobile 6 using newer Visual Studio than VS2008. Even for Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 and Windows CE6 programming you need Visual Studio 2008.